# the efficient way of using np.random.uniform to generate a batch of variable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

In a simulation, I would like to generate a batch of random numbers, for instance `3`. Besides, each random number corresponds to a different upper bound. For instance, `var1` has upper bound of `10`; `var2` has upper bound of `25`; and `var3` has upper bound of `30`. Naturally, I can write a loop to generate it. Is that possible to have a more efficient way to generate it using `numpy.random.uniform`.

Comment: If creating only a few at a time, the python `random` package is faster than `np.random`.  The numpy code is best for many at at time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest sampling in [0,1] and then scaling:

```py
import numpy as np
random_list = np.multiply(np.random.uniform(size=3), [10,25,30])
```

Comment: Hi! Glad that you accepted this answer but I learned something in @hpaulj's answer, I think it is better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

`uniform` docs says it can take array like low/high values:

```
In [105]: np.random.uniform(0,(10,25,30))
Out[105]: array([ 8.19116219, 21.65392271, 28.97388141])
```

Comment: I learned something about `np.random.uniform`, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
batch_size = 10
var1 = np.random.uniform(0.0, 10.0, batch_size)
var2 = np.random.uniform(0.0, 25.0, batch_size)
var3 = np.random.uniform(0.0, 30.0, batch_size)
```